# I can't activate a custom chrome content script extension outside of developer mode

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am having problem activating my own custom made script. It's working in the developer mode, when I load it as a directory. But when I pack it using the method provided by chrome it does not work.

It creates a .pem and .crx file, and when I drag and drop the extension inside the chrome://extensions page it shows. When pressing f5 it is deactivated every time, and when I check "also allow in incognito mode", that checkbox disappears immediately and doesn't come back.

Below my manifest file contents:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Test script",
"version": "0.1",
"incognito": "split",
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "http://mail.google.com/*",
            "https://mail.google.com/*",
            "https://accounts.google.com/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "jquery-2.1.4.min.js",
            "content.js"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Any clue what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome [blocks extension installs on Windows](http://chrome.blogspot.lt/2014/05/protecting-chrome-users-from-malicious.html) unless they come from Chrome Web Store.

Install Chrome from a [developer channel](https://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) or use another OS.